# Emscripten libc with gettext

Tags: build, gettext, emscripten, nls

I try to build 7kaa and it builds, but without nls. It shown libc does not have gettext support. How to build project with gettext.

I do:

```
emcc --show-ports
```

There was not gettext.

I found https://github.com/abergmeier/emscripten-gettext, but did not known, how to integrate it.